# Drag-n-Move - How to avoid RecyclerView background fill the entire screen even there's only a few items in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Currently, I'm implementing drag-n-move feature according to https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-6a6f0c422efd and code example from https://github.com/iPaulPro/Android-ItemTouchHelper-Demo/

Here's the outcome

[image]

I would like to have background of `RecycleView` to be visible, when the item is being moved.

Here's changes I had did

1. Set `RecycleView` background color to red - `recyclerView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);`
2. Provide a solid white color, on the item.

   ```
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/text"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
       android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/handle"
       android:layout_width="?listPreferredItemHeight"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
       android:scaleType="center"
       android:src="@drawable/ic_reorder_grey_500_24dp" />
   ```

Here's my desired outcome.

[image]

However, there's 1 shortcoming. When, there's only a few items in `RecyclerView`. Those empty area will also be filled with background color. Please see the below screenshot. The below `RecyclerView` only contain 3 items.

[image]

I had try to make `RecyclerView`'s height `wrap_content`

```
recyclerView.setLayoutParams(
        new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        )
);
```

However, it makes no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `RecyclerView` is longer than the area allocated to it on the screen then there is no issue: Just set the background color of the `RecyclerView` to red. However, if the items in the `RecyclerView` do not fill up the space allocated to the `RecyclerView` in the layout then you will see the red background in the empty space. This is what you want to eliminate.

To do this, set a `OnGlobalLayoutListener` on the `RecyclerView` and check if there is excess space or not. If there is not excess space, then just set the background color to red; otherwise, create a `BitmapDrawable` filled with red and properly sized to provide a background to just the items on the screen and not large enough to spill into the excess area.

Here is the code that accomplishes this in `RecyclerListFragment` of the project you mention.

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final RecyclerView recyclerView = new RecyclerView(container.getContext());
    recyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            recyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            if (recyclerView.getChildCount() == 0) {
                return;
            }

            int lastChildBottom = recyclerView.getChildAt(recyclerView.getChildCount() - 1).getBottom();
            if (lastChildBottom >= recyclerView.getHeight()) {
                recyclerView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                return;
            }
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(recyclerView.getWidth(), lastChildBottom, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            bitmap.eraseColor(Color.RED);
            BitmapDrawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
            d.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
            recyclerView.setBackground(d);
            recyclerView.invalidate();
        }
    });
    return recyclerView;
}
```

Here is a video of the effect:

[image]

If you have a swipe-to-remove gesture implemented, you will also have to invoke the listener when an item is removed. I also had to set the background color to a non-zero value in `onItemClear()` of `RecyclerListAdapter`.

---

An easier way is to define a drawable that can be set as a background to a `RecyclerView` that draws only behind the item views.

```
public class RecyclerViewBackground extends Drawable {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Paint mPaint;

    RecyclerViewBackground() {
        super();
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (mRecyclerView.getChildCount() == 0) {
            return;
        }

        int bottom = mRecyclerView.getChildAt(mRecyclerView.getChildCount() - 1).getBottom();
        if (bottom >= mRecyclerView.getHeight()) {
            bottom = mRecyclerView.getHeight();
        }
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), bottom, mPaint);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter colorFilter) {
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.OPAQUE;
    }

    public void attachRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        mRecyclerView = recyclerView;
    }
}
```

Attach this `Drawable` to the `RecyclerView` as follows:

```
RecyclerViewBackground bg = new RecyclerViewBackground();
bg.attachRecyclerView(recyclerView);
recyclerView.setBackground(bg);
```

This will also take care of swipe to delete.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you aware that, when u move an item down, its neighbor text is being slide up first, only then the neighbor white background card will be slide up later on.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng That is because the items have a transparent background. Apply a white background to the `FrameLayout` of `item_main` and the red will not bleed through.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng I see what you mean. The appearance isn't exactly like setting the background color. The solution may delve into the default animation. An alternative, depending upon your requirements, would be to set the background color and fill the `RecyclerView` with dummy entries so the background doesn't show at the end. Maybe just have one big entry to cover the last part.