# How to highlight the drop target location when using drag and drop with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, drag-and-drop

I'm currently using this solution for the recycler view drag and drop: https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-6a6f0c422efd

I have no issues dragging and dropping, however, I would like to show a grey box in the area where the view being dragged, would be dropped. A link to what I'm talking about is here: https://share.getcloudapp.com/9Zu07YAB

You can see there is a faint gray box in the "drop zone" of the view.

Another example is shown in the image below, where there is that gray placeholder view, where the dragged item would be dropped at.

[image: Here's another example of the sort of design I'd be looking for]

Comment: It seems impossible to do, or very hard at the very minimum

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but can't you just add a background to your item view? How this would work is explained under _Indicating the Selected View_  [here](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-6a6f0c422efd) which you reference.

Comment: @Cheticamp That would change the background of the view being dragged. I'd like a way for there to be a placeholder view where the item would be dropped into.

Comment: onDraw

public void onDraw (Canvas c, 
                RecyclerView parent, 
                RecyclerView.State state)
Draw any appropriate decorations into the Canvas supplied to the RecyclerView. Any content drawn by this method will be drawn before the item views are drawn, and will thus appear underneath the views.

Comment: i think experimenting with this override method can definetly help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49821458/drag-n-move-how-to-avoid-recyclerview-background-fill-the-entire-screen-even-t this link will help you out